# LED brightness and Arduino ports

Tags: arduino-uno

Hi I am learning Arduino. Pin 13 lights the LED's very brightly. With subsequent LED's on other ports the LED's are much less bright than the one on 13.

Anyone know what is going on?

regards

Comment: Wiring? Code? We're not psychic, you know...

Comment: my guess is the you are using two different kinds of LEDs ..... no other guesses are possible because you provided zero information

Comment: I used the example program in Uno called Blink.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have cheap crappy inefficient leds on the other pins. Or you have the wrong value resistor in series with them. If they are not from the same batch, with the same resistor, you can't really complain. Maybe they are for a higher voltage. (because of the resistor value)

Are you sure you set the port pins for output?

```
pinMode(Output_PIN, OUTPUT);
```

Comment: I used this basic code then cut and pasted it and added two more pins 12 and 11. The LED's all came in a starter kit so I assume they are the same. 
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

Comment: The leds in the starter kit are probably a different size compared to the led on the board. Probably through hole parts, so they are not the same as what was used on the board.  Can you provide a link to the kit you bought?

Comment: Haven't got supplier details for my kit. Can you recommend a good starter kit and supplier details.